# What does D3.js "Data" function expect as its first argument?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, d3.js

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to do a data bind combining an array onto an existing svg map.

The array contains objects which have a `name` property that corresponds to the `id` property of the svg elements in the d3 selection.

I'm doing the data-join like this:

```
mySelection.data(
  [
    {"name": "county1"},
    {"name": "county2"},
    {"name": "county3"}
  ],                 
  function (datum, index) {
    if (this.getAttribute("id") === datum["name"]) {
      return datum;
  });
```

However when I run it I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

I've tried stepping through the code with a debugger, and it looks to me like the problem is that when d3 calls my key function, the `datum` argument is empty. So I can only assume it doesn't like like the format of the data array.

I've tried reading the documentation on the data function [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data), unfortunately it isn't very clear about what format the function expects for its first argument besides that it should be an "array of data".

Can you help me work out why my data bind isn't working?

Here is a jsFiddle using my actual data: http://jsfiddle.net/Racheet/GG3d5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `.data()` is a function that is executed for each data element and each DOM element in `myselection`. It is passed the data and assumed to return whatever allows to match data and DOM elements. In your case, this would be `.name`.

Your example doesn't have any data bound to the elements, so this doesn't work. You can however leverage this fact and check whether there is data bound and if not, return the ID of the DOM element:

```
provinces.data(data, function(d) { return d ? d.name : this.getAttribute("id"); });
```

Note that after this operation, the DOM elements will have data bound to them and the key function should work as expected. Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GG3d5/1/).

Comment: I think I understand, but I'm not 100% on this. The key function is run on BOTH the data array and the elements array, and in both case needs to return a string. D3 will then take those strings and then in any cases where a string for a data array cell and the string for an html element line up, it will bind one to the other. Am I correct? and does this then allow many to one binding between the array and the elements?

Comment: The first part is correct. Imagine for example that the key function returns `["foo", "bar", "foobar"]` for the data and `["foo", "foobar", "bla"]` for the DOM elements. In this case, `"foo"` and `"foobar"` are matched (in the update selection), `"foobar"` is only in the data but not the DOM (and will be in the enter selection) and `"bla"` is only in the DOM but not the data (will be in the exit selection). There is no many to one binding though, the first element matches (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp9eX/) for a quick demo).

Comment: Thanks again, that really helped me get my head around what was going on.